# error: cannot find symbol import android.widget.selector;

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My Android Studio Build fails with this error message, after updating several dependencies. I also switched from using "dataBinding{
enabled = true
}"
to "viewBinding true" I can't find a resolution for this anywhere. I already tried cleaning, rebuilding, invalidating caches and restarting the computer multiple times. Previous suggestions to similar questions didn't resolve this either. Do i have to start a new android studio project and copy over my code?

> C:\Users\seric\AndroidStudioProjects\Futlytics\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\futlytics\databinding\ToggleStyleBinding.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
> import android.widget.selector;

I dont even use anything called ToggleStyleBinding.

My gradle files look like this:

**Module**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    //apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
        buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.futlytics"
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
        /*dataBinding{
            enabled = true
        }*/
        buildFeatures {
            mlModelBinding true
            viewBinding true
        }
    
    
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
        //implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.4'
        //implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.4'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.4'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.4'
        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0-rc1'
        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc1'
        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.3'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
        implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:16.1.3'
        implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'
    
        // CameraX
        implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-alpha03"
        implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-alpha03"
        implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha23"
    
        //Firebase
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.7.0')
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:20.0.3'
    
    
    }

Projectapply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.futlytics"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    /*dataBinding{
        enabled = true
    }*/
    buildFeatures {
        mlModelBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    //implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.4'
    //implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.4'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0-rc1'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc1'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:16.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'

    // CameraX
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha23"

    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.7.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:20.0.3'


}
```

**Project**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.31"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.4"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue when accidentally placed xml with `<selector>` to "layout" folder (instead of "drawable"). Android Studio then tries to make a Binding for it as for layout.

Answer (score 2):

build.gradle(:app) -> just change TRUE to FALSE. (idk what viewBiding does, but my quite advanced app works (again) without error)

```
buildFeatures {
        viewBinding false
}
```

Comment: Please, don't suggest to disable a feature as a solution if you don't know what could happen in other projects.
ViewBinding is a very useful feature, and the fact that you're not using it in your project doesn't mean that it's not advanced, it means that it's probably less efficent in terms of views managing.

Read more about it in the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

I suggest you to start implementing it, because it really simplifies your developement, and more than that it's more efficient than using any findView method on your own.